# Twitter accounts of localized Stack Overflow sites use the old versions of the logo

Tags: bug, status-completed, stack-overflow, design, twitter

Compare the Twitter icons: [@StackOverflow](https://twitter.com/StackOverflow) uses the new logo.

[image: SO]

[@ruStackOverflow](https://twitter.com/ruStackOverflow) has a modified icon based on previous logo.

[image: ruSO]

[@StackOverflowPT](https://twitter.com/StackOverflowPT) and [Stack Overflow日本語版](https://twitter.com/jaStackOverflow) went retro all the way, using the original logo.

[image: ptSO]

These should probably be replaced by the sites' favicons:

[image: ruicon]      and      [image: pticon]      and      
[image: jaicon]

(And it wouldn't hurt if ja.SO Twitter account had a link to the site...)

Comment: No end to posts like this . . .

Comment: And I didn't even look at their Facebook, Google+ and Pinterest pages...

Comment: @inɒzɘmɒЯ.A.M I suspect this whole logo change is actually a conspiracy to boost the overall reputation in MSE... ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks for pointing this out. The logos have been updated.